# java 8 string to date - format dd-MMM-yy

Tags: date, parsing, java-8

the following code does not work:  (take care that the string containing the date is localized)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy", new Locale("es")); 
LocalDate parse = LocalDate.parse("13-DIC-16", formatter);
```

I get:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13-DIC-16' could not be parsed at index 3
```

What does "index 3" mean?

How to parse with java 8 dates in the format dd-MMM-yy (using the correct locale)?

I cannot modify the original query which provides the strings.

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that the API is case sensitive; a case-insensitive parser must be built, see the linked question. `"DIC"` cannot be parsed (`'D'` is the index 3 at `'13-DIC-16'`).

Comment: Thanks! That is the issue, now it works.